# Python [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:

Tags: python

My current working directory is

```
C:\Users\18327\Desktop
```

I have the following code:

```
#Load os module
import os

#this is the abs path of my Temp folder
my_path = "C:/Users/18327/Desktop/New/Temp/"

#my parent folders
start = "C:/Users/18327/Desktop"

relative_path = os.path.relpath(my_path, start)

#relative path is New\Temp
print(relative_path)

#get and print current path of the current machine
current_path = os.getcwd()
print('current path is {}'.format(current_path))

#combine them

temp_path = os.path.join(current_path,
                            relative_path)
print(temp_path)


#set the path to your current medline folder

os.chdir(temp_path)
```

The first time I ran it I got the desired path I wanted, which is

```
New\Temp
current path is C:\Users\18327\Desktop
C:\Users\18327\Desktop\New\Temp
```

However, when I ran the code again, I got

```
New\Temp
current path is C:\Users\18327\Desktop\New\Temp
C:\Users\18327\Desktop\New\Temp\New\Temp
*** FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\18327\\Desktop\\New\\Temp\\New\\Temp'
```

How do I modify the code so that each time I run it I get the result

```
C:\Users\18327\Desktop\New\Temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens since you're changing the working dir with `os.chdir` and not changing it back to where it was at the end of your run, while also using relative paths instead of absolute paths.

You could add `old_working_dir = os.os.getcwd()` at the start of your file and `os.chdir(old_working_dir)` at the end to return to where you were and have it run again as intended, but that's a bit hacky for my taste.

A much better solution would be to not use `chdir` at all, and make your script work with absolute paths instead of relative ones if possible.

Also, check out `pathlib` for many easier ways to deal with file paths.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got the idea. The reason I am using the relative path is that I wish to run it from another computer with the New\Temp

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace in that case use my idea of changing back to the old working dir once you're done